# page.db size in SwiftMQ implementation of JMS

Tags: java, database, jms, rabbitmq, message-queue

In my product I am using SwiftMQ as the messaging service. I see that it uses a page.dg file and I read that it is the JMS transactional file. I see that it is growing very big in my enviroment upto 9 gb. I did some research in the net but couldnet get clear answer to my doubts. Basically -- 1. Why is page.db file used for and what is the implication of deleting this file manually. Will it have any adverse affect? Also, can I control the growth of this file beyond a certain configurable size? Any clarity on these answers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Will really appreciate if someone could educate me about the page.db file used in SwiftMQ.

Comment: Why not consult the [docs](http://www.swiftmq.com/products/router/swiftlets/sys_store/introduction/index.html)? There's a nice and comprehensive description of the store and the files used in the store (page.db, transaction.log).

Answer (score 0):

we use SwiftMQ as well on our linux servers. As far as I know the page.db and transaction files is like a 'log' of the messages in the queues.

If you manually delete the page.db and transaction file it will remove any messages that are in your queues at that time. I have done this before.

I am however not sure about controlling the growth of the file?

Answer (score 0):

The page.db contains is the actual persistent data store (contains pages and is a database so that's for the name ;-)). Every change is recorded in the transaction.log. This is sync'ed during a checkpoint.

The question why a page.db grows is quite simple. There is one or more queues that have huge back logs of persistent messages. In many case these are dead durable subscribers. So just check with SwiftMQ Explorer: Queue Manager Swiftlet / Usage, right click, "Show Entity Table". Click on the "Message Count" column to order by message count. This should help to identify queues with backlogs.

Btw, there is a [SwiftMQ User Forum](http://swiftmq-jms-forum.688.n7.nabble.com) where will have more chance that your questions get answered.

Answer (score 0):

page.db is used to store persistent messages that comes into a queue, they will be removed once they are consumed by a consumer. if you want to limit the maximum size of the page.db its not possible, however a workaround would be to analyse your traffic (see how much space a message takes [page.db size / no of messages in all queues at a time]) and then define a max message limit on your queues.